# Is sys.objects modify_date a reliable way to check the las time a table was modified in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I am using `modify_date` column in `sys.objects` to check the last time a table has been modified using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    name, create_date, modify_date, type, type_desc
FROM
    sys.objects
WHERE 
    type IN ('P', 'TR', 'TF', 'U', 'X')
    AND modify_date >= '2021-01-01' 
ORDER BY
    modify_date DESC
```

I keep getting recent dates for `modify_Date` even though alterations haven't been made to any of these tables recently. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says it also changes when an index on the table or view is created or altered but changes haven't been made on index either.

Can something else be triggering the `modify_date` change?

Comment: Do you have code that uses sp_recompile with the table as a target?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. These is a database with a size around 25 Gb and is used by multiple systems. I will be checking if any of these systems uses sp_recompile.  Thanks fot the tip @MartinSmith .

Comment: @AaronLemus Checksum also helps in this to check whether table gets modified. 
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) FROM yourTable WITH (NOLOCK); You should get the same checksum if no modification

Comment: I'd recommend using `FROM sys.tables` which allows you to drop that check for the object type ...